# Can I simulate Apple pay cards validation errors?

Tags: ios, applepay

I have implemented apple pay for the app I am working at the moment, but now I would like to try different error cases, like an expired card, a declined payment, etc...

I could not find in the sandbox testing [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/) any faulty cards.

Is it possible to reproduce these different cases easily?